# Query conversation_id with tweepy recent search to obtain tweet responses

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

According to Twitter API documentation, the conversation_id can be used to obtained threads. To do that, one should use conversation_id in a tweet search query (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id). Twitter API documentation also says the conversation_id should be used in search tweet query like this:

[image]

I have used tweepy to fetch tweets search results like this and it worked well:

```
tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
                              query = 'covid19 lang:cs OR corona lang:cs OR korona lang:cs OR covid lang:cs OR kovid lang:cs OR koronavirus lang:cs \
                                        OR koronavir lang:cs OR coronavirus lang:cs',
```

However, using this piece of code with conversation_id as the query has not worked - does anyone know why this might be the case?

```
responses_from_conversations = []
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
                              query = 'conversation_id:1494772850527457289',):
                              
                            responses_from_conversations.append(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `user_auth = True` and then it worked.

```
responses_from_conversations = []
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,
                              query = 'conversation_id:1494772850527457289', user_auth = True):  
    responses_from_conversations.append(response)
```

Comment: Can I ask how you do authentication? bearer?